# Fill NSMutableArray in a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *numbers;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {

        [numbers addObject:counter];

    }

}
```

I tried to fill up the array numbers with a for loop counting from 0 - 9 but I don't know how to do so. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`NSArray` cannot contain primitives, you must add objects to it.

Objects that correspond to integers are `NSNumber`s. You can make them using the old syntax, like this,

```
[numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:counter]];
```

or using the new syntax, like this:

```
[numbers addObject:@(counter)];
```

It goes without saying that before adding objects to the array you need to create it:

```
numbers = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: And, of course, before you can even use the array you have to create it.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for mentioning it, forgetting to create an array is indeed a rather common omission.